# Correct way to parse a String to DirectoryInfo?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program and to avoid complication I need to parse a given string variable to be a DirectoryInfo.
I was wondering if it were possible to parse a string to a DirectoryInfo. 
If it is, how does one go about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: It has constructor accepting string ... search MSDN first, please.

Comment: What does the value in the string variable look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(string);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx)

MSDN, linked above, provides you the exceptions in case the string is invalid.  Note: this is NOT if the directory exists.  MSDN also makes note of this in the Remarks.  You must then do:

```
if(di.Exists)
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's not *parsing*, but the [constructor for `DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx) takes the path as a string:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyDir");
```