# SSIS Script to Delete and Create Folders

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a loop that runs and creates a bunch of files per folder.  The folders are uniquely named based on the order range, so they can change.  And the folder must exist or the loop crashes.

I want to create a script that will delete all subfolders and files in each subfolder, from a root dir.
ie

```
Root = C:\Output\
SubFolder = C:\Output\T1-500\
SubFolder = C:\Output\T501-1010\
SubFolder = C:\Output\T1011-3076\
```

Then have it create folders as needed on the fly.
I tried:

```
public void Main()
    {
        // Deletes subfolders and files in the main folder
        EmptyFolder(Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"]);

        // Creates new folder on the fly
        if (Directory.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"].Value = 0))
            Dts.TaskResult = Directory.CreateDirectory(Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"]);
    }


    private void EmptyFolder(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            EmptyFolder(subfolder);
        }
    }
```

It doesn't seem to pick up my package level variables, and won't let me add new ones.
[image]

I get the following when I try to use my folder variable:
[image]

Comment: To remove folders on the command line you can use `RD <yourfolder> /S /Q`.

Comment: What does "It doesn't seem to pick up my package level variables" mean? are you getting an error or are you unable to add them in the dialog?

Comment: Added error from variable

Comment: Your variable is a string. That method doesn’t take a string. You need an extra step to convert it to a “DirectoryInfo” object.

Comment: i.e. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335754/correct-way-to-parse-a-string-to-directoryinfo. _Please Note_ in future please post the actual error, don't post things like "It doesn't seem to pick up my package level variables" - that doesn't mean anything. If you explain the full issue upfront it saves a lot of back and forth and half the time you solve it yourself anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means you are passing in the wrong data type. Try this.

Instead of this:

```
EmptyFolder(Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"]);
```

Use this:

```
String folderName = (string)Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"].Value;
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
EmptyFolder(di);
```

There is probably a way to put all of it on one line but start with that.

As mentioned in comments below, the `(string)` cast may not be necessary if you just use the `Value` property - please also try that.

You will probably also need to use your new `folderName` string variable in other parts of your code.

As I mentioned in the comments you can also just run a command line like this to remove a folder and all subfolders

```
RD <yourfolder> /S /Q
```

Comment: We have to put .Value for reading the value of the variable. DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"].Value); I think if you put that, you dont need to convert into string. [Use SSIS Variable](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22194.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-task.aspx)

Comment: You're probably right - thanks for your addition. I'll check and add it to the answer

Comment: hmm this says it needs to be explicitly cast https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/using-variables-in-the-script-task?view=sql-server-2017 but I'll add value

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.